# Remix Form sends Get request after post request

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have a problem in my remixjs code

When I try to send a post request using Form in remixjs it sends a POST and after that a Get request , the Form component is a pre defined component in remix js and it should preventDefault

I don't know why ? and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually with a form, your users are most likely mutating data on the server. Remix revalidates your data by running all the loaders for that route when an action is performed. This is done so your UI is sync with your data.

This is also what your browser does when you use a regular form. It posts to the server and a new document is fetched with fresh data. Remix is built upon such Web Standards. Get good at Remix, get good at the web .